# Assign Text of 2d array of buttons

Tags: android, arrays, button

In android I have array of buttons that I declare like this 
Button grid[][] = new Button[3][3];

I then set grid[0][0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Middle_Middle) which does exist

when I try to then change the text of it by

calling grid[0][0].setText("U");

I crash. I know it is not the declare or setting of the array because it only crashes when I go into the function that I am using to set the text. Any ideas on why this would crash

Comment: It would help if you posted your Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

If Button.setText() is throwing a NullPointerException, then the button in your Layout (R.id.Middle_Middle) must not currently be inflated/exist in your content View.

Since Button grid[][] = new Button[3][3]; doesn't actually create the Buttons you're trying to access, it would throw the NPE when you try to set the text (since your findViewById() method is returning null when trying to set the single one).

You need to actually instantiate the Buttons before accessing them.

Eg.

```
Button grid[][] = new Button[3][3];
for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
           grid[i][j] = new Button(context);
           parent.addView(grid[i][j]);
       }
}
```

Unless you're manually setting the Buttons using findViewById() for each, but that seems like a lot of extra work to keep references for the buttons in a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that findViewByID(R.id.Middle_Middle) return not null element?

Make sure that first do setContentView of your layout and after get the elements.

Comment: yes. I tried it by setting it like this
Button t = (Button)findviewById(R.id.Middle_Middle);
then t.setText("U"); and it worked but in the array it does not.

Comment: I think this is my issue I do it before I do the setContentView

Comment: Jums... Can you add the logcat crash report?